# Viewing a remote camera stream in Scratch

Tags: raspberry-pi, ip-camera, mit-scratch

I'm doing a project for my son where we're going to have a remote Pi Zero with a camera and various sensors and actuators, connected via wired Ethernet to a Pi 3 as a controller with a Scratch GUI.

Seems like I can get a local camera to send video to the background of the Scratch project, or I can get a remote camera to stream back to e.g. VLC Player using RTSP.

Being as how I want to teach my son how to build a scratch GUI on the Pi3 to remote control the sensors and actuators on the Pi Zero, I'd really like the rtsp video stream to show up as the Scratch project background so I don't have to have a separate VLC window open.

So... how to pick up an RTSP video stream and send it to the Scratch backdrop?

Anyone got any ideas as to where I could start? I have intermediate raspbian, python and Scratch skills.

Thanks in advance,
Ben

Comment: I have also not much scratch experience, but why do you think it is possible to have a live video stream in scratch ?  I have not heard of this scratch feature.  Maybe it is something that is foreseen in scratch 3 ?

Comment: Hi JanVdA, try using the [Video () block](https://en.scratch-wiki.info/wiki/Turn_Video_()_(block)).

Instructions [here](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/10454508/), demo at the end.

Comment: Sorry not a very smart comment from me.

Comment: Hi JanVdA. Your comment was fine with me. It consisted of a (presumably) true statement, a valid question (which I answered), a (presumably) true statement and an uninformed speculation. Uninformed is ok with me. It doesn't strike me as reasonable to require you to fact-check when actually you're just trying to help. In summary... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild suggestion. Maybe it is possible to access your USB camera on the remote pi zero as a local camera using remote USB (I admit I have never tried it).

This functionality is provided by the package usbip

- https://packages.debian.org/jessie/usbip

You can install this package using the following command on both raspberry pi devices: 
`sudo apt-get install usbip`

For more information about the setup enter the command:
`man usbip`.

Comment: Interesting. This goes straight to the top of my list of ways to try and solve this problem. I'm a bit flat out at the moment, but when I get a chance I might take a whack at this and report back. Thanks!